# how to use window command line to capture packets/s on wireshark's capinfos interface

Tags: windows, wireshark

Does anyone know how to capture the packets/s on Wireshar's capinfos interface using window command line?

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGpst.png)

thank you

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There are many command-line tools that allow you to capture packets - [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html), [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/)/[`WinDump`](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/) and [`RawCap`](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to name a few.  The [Wireshark Tools wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) lists these and many other tools you might find useful.